# How to switch between iframes using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I'm trying to make a script to checkout on a Shopify site and I was able to find the iframe for the card number, but was not able to find the iframe for the name on the card (2nd iframe). Is there any way to enter in a value for that iframe?

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@autocomplete="cc-number"]').send_keys("1234")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-card-field-placeholder="Name on card"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@autocomplete="cc-name"]').send_keys("First Last")
```

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@autocomplete="cc-name"]').send_keys("First Last")
```

and it gives me Unable to locate element

Image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgeF1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *card number* and *name* fields are in different `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* for the **card number** field.
- Switch to the *Default Content*
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* for the **name** field.
- You can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe' and starts-with(@id, 'card-fields-number')]")))
  # perform other operations
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe' and starts-with(@id, 'card-fields-name')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 0):

Use unique locator as you do for any other elements

The syntax for switch to frame is

```
   driver.switch_to.frame(WebElement)
```

So you don't need use just tag name , you can use xpath , Id , css etc like anyothr element

We use tag usually because there will be only one iframe in most cases . If you have multiple iframes find each iframes uniquely as you do for other elements using any other attributes like I'd,class etc of the specific iframe

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="card-fields-name-fpsn1ey65to00000"]'))`

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work
```driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('iframe[id="card-fields-name-fpsn1ey65to00000"]'))```

Comment: You have to put @id not id

Comment: //iframes[@id="!$!+

Comment: What you have used is a css locator not xpath , read basic element locators in xpatha and css

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped ,also the previous one . It's not a good practice to remove accepted answers as we put time and effort to debug and help you fix your code . Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the parent tag as it has a more identifiable div tag that can be xpathed to.This way you can just go to the iframe you want before finding the input tag to send keys to.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("div[@data-card-fields='number']/iframe"))
```

Comment: hmm, I just tried this and it's giving me "Unable to locate element". I tried switching back to default content and back and neither work