# Selenium Selection Problem with Python - Selecting source srcset

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Sorry for being a bit vague in the title, I don't know the right terminology.

I would like to select the text that follows the highlighted '<source srcset' tag in the below screenshot:

[image: inspect source]

It doesn't work if I try to select the class `css-1nfcn93`, and I don't know how to select on anything deeper into the tree.  I assume I want xpath, but I don't understand how that works yet.

Some code that does not work ('WebElement has no len()'):

```
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.theguardian.com/football/2020/dec/19/burnley-wolves-match-preview-premier-league')
text = d.find_element_by_css_selector('div.css-1nfcn93')
print(len(text))
d.quit()
```

Comment: The term is `attribute`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium) post or [this blog](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/getattribute-method-in-selenium).

Answer (score 1):

To get all source elements use:

```
source_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.css-1nfcn93 source')
```

This will give you a list of sources. From there you can get the content of the attribute you are looking for

```
for source in source_elements:
    print(len(source.get_attribute('srcset'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The text **Burnley v Wolves** is the value of the `alt` attribute and to extract it you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the **I'm happy** *element to be clickable* and click on it.
- Switch to the [Default Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138057/how-to-switch-between-iframes-using-selenium-and-python/65142572#65142572)
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.theguardian.com/football/2020/dec/19/burnley-wolves-match-preview-premier-league")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='sp_message_iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title$='m happy']"))).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "picture[itemprop='contentUrl'] img"))).get_attribute("alt"))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.theguardian.com/football/2020/dec/19/burnley-wolves-match-preview-premier-league")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'sp_message_iframe')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@title, 'm happy')]"))).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//picture[@itemprop='contentUrl']//img"))).get_attribute("alt"))
    ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Burnley v Wolves
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [How to switch between iframes using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138057/how-to-switch-between-iframes-using-selenium-and-python/65142572#65142572)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)